# Change POST design of divi theme

Tags: wordpress, divi-theme

Hi i am developing a website using DIVI theme.
I want to change WordPress post design. 
Please find bellow attached two images.

[This is what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWyPA.jpg)
[This is my current design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teniB.png)

Please answer in detail and also let me know that in which file this code exists in files so i can edit it.
And moreover you can suggest me best techniques to use divi theme, I have purchased complete package of divi theme.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you done any research at all, or have you tried anything? Visit the [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/) for functions that you can use in your template files.

Comment: Yes michael yes i spend 2 days to find any solution but i could,nt be able to find it...Actually i am using DIVI theme for first time. If i develop custom theme then its very easy but i am customizing divi theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divi by default doesn't allow this.. but you can Show the category and Comments first..
then edit the post archive .php

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using the [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/) or [Wordpress Developer](https://codex.wordpress.org/) references.

Below you'll find a little kickstart for you how you could do that, just change the classes to your needs. To get the expected results use this code within [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

You can use [`comments_number()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_number) to display the current amount of comments for each post:

e.g.

```
<div class="comments-wrapper">
 <i class="icon-class"></i>
 <p class="comments-count"><?php comments_number( 'No Comment', 'One Comment', '% Comments' ); ?></p>
</div>
```

And you can use [`the_category()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category) to display the current category of the post:

e.g.

```
<div class="category-wrapper">
 <i class="icon-class"></i>
 <p class="category"><?php the_category( ' ' ); ?></p>
</div>
```

Comment: actually i have added post on page using divi page builder, I ma not unable to fine the file where i will have to make change?

Answer (score 0):

here you have to select post category and tag and updated Divi theme it will show automatically if you select categories and tags post type